# Как проявлять текст по очереди в массиве, Unity2D, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я имею данный скрипт, сразу скажу что вот данная строка отвечает за построчное появление одного текста:

```
IEnumerator showText(string text)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= text.Length)
    {
        textUI.text = text.Substring(0, i);
        i++;
    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    }
}
```

Дальше вот сам скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TypeText : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text textUI;
    [TextArea(3, 10)]
    public string[] text;
    int ColvoText;

    void Start()
    {
        textUI = GetComponent<Text>();
        StartCoroutine("showText", text);
    }

    void Update() {
    }

    IEnumerator showText(string text)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= text.Length)
        {
            textUI.text = text.Substring(0, i);
            i++;
        
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }
    }
}
```

Опять же повторюсь, я хочу сделать появление текстов с очередью, то есть сначала один текст спустя 5 секунд другой и тд.

Comment: Этот код не работает? Как он работает и как должен работать?

Comment: Всмысле, я же написал, я сделал массив (раньше был обычный string без массива), и сделал его публичным. После написал в методе старт запустил корутину, чтобы текст взятый из String, писался по буквенно, но мне не достаточно одного текста, мне нужно чтобы весь текст вписанный в массив, писался по очередно но я не знаю как это сделать!!!

Comment: https://unitycoder.com/blog/2015/12/03/ui-text-typewriter-effect-script/ с этого примера чтоли делали?

Comment: нет, я писал с другого, как говорится смысл придумывать то что уже имеется!

Comment: вы можете дать ответ на мой вопрос?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка это массив символов, массив строк выглядит как массив массивов. Значит нужен цикл в цикле.

```cs
IEnumerator showText(string[] lines)
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            textUI.text = line.Substring(0, i);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    }
}
```

Comment: если сработает балл!!!)

Comment: @anonimchel здесь есть маленький косяк, после того как последняя строка отпечатается полностью, корутина еще 5 секунд потупит и только потом завершится. Но я уверен, вы сможете теперь доработать так, как вам нужно.

Comment: Лучший, спасибо!!!!!!

Comment: конечно смогу спасибо!

Comment: Пишем готовые куски кода для копирования из интернетов?

Comment: @Yaroslav так точно, копируйте xD. Ну или вот [пободрее пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62611838/12888024).